# How to avoid "cell formatting" of GridEX from being overridden by "selected row formatting"?

Tags: c#, janus, gridex

I use Janus 3.5 with C#. I have a grid (GridEX) and implemented the "FormattingRow event" to change the background color of certains cells by setting their "GridEXCell.FormatStyle". This works fine.

However, as soon as a row of my grid is selected, my cell formatting is overridden by the one defined at "GridEX.SelectedFormatStyle" level.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks,

Danny